# Optimizing Windows XP to use less HD access

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, memory, performance, virtual-memory

I have a corporate laptop with a great processor and 4 gigs of RAM, however the HD is ancient, we're talking 4200RPM here, roundabouts.

Programs *run* great, but load horribly, horribly slow.

Any configuration/setting tips to get Windows XP to lean as much on physical memory as possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can [Use XP's Prefetch feature to improve system performance](http://www.zdnetasia.com/insight/software/0,39044822,39172453,00.htm) :

The registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management\PrefetchParameters` contains `EnablePrefetcher` which may have the following values:

- 0—Disable
- 1—Application Launch Prefetch
- 2—Boot Prefetch
- 3—Prefetch everything

To change the value, double-click it. You'll then see the Edit DWORD Value screen. Enter the value representing the level of prefetching you want in the Value Data field.

Try to set it to 3 and see whether that improves the performance.

Comment: Thanks Harry. I've up vote you but I need 15 rep to do so ;) I will try this out ASAP but it looks promising.

Comment: Is 3, Prefetch everything, not the default setting? It is set that way on all three XP machines at my immediate disposal. I was hoping to add another useful tweak. :)

Comment: Wow, shockingly it was already set to 3. I guess that doesn't bode well for me? D:

Comment: XP will preserve up to 128 prefetches. When this limit is reached it will keep only the 32 most frequently used files and dump all the others. So maybe your problem is the opposite: too many prefetches. What happens if you set EnablePrefetcher to 1 and delete all files in c:\windows\prefetch and let XP re-prefetch ?

Comment: Changing it to 1 seemed to have some impact. I'll continue to monitor.

Answer (score -1):

One solution to this problem which is increasingly common is to replace the HDD with a SSD.  [Benchmarks](http://www.anandtech.com/storage/showdoc.aspx?i=3631&p=22) are showing *massive* improvements in throughput and (subjectively) in overall pep/responsiveness.

Comment: Admittedly, that doesn't directly address your question of optimizing Windows XP.  If the loading is slow because it's HDD-intensive, have you tried the usual precursors, like defragging your HDD and pagefile?

Comment: Yes, I have done a full defrag and have tried several virtual memory settings. Hardware changes are *not* an option, I need software solutions only.

Comment: 7200rpm hard drive will be a lot cheaper than a decent SSD at the moment.

Comment: Absolutely.  And also much slower, from every review I've read lately.  Sometimes cost becomes secondary (within reason, of course.)